# What engines do the native speech recognitions on mobile phones use?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on a mobile app that makes heavily use of speech-to-text functionalities, so I'm trying to figure out whats the best solution to do so.

I came across the Google Cloud Speech API and the Microsoft Bing Speech API, but there are a few questions now:

1. What engine does a native android device call for, if i simply use the SpeechRecognizer class? Is it the same as being used by the Google Cloud Speech API?
2. What Engine does the iOS native Speech Recognition use? Can it be accessed by other, non-apple devices (maybe via REST)?
3. What engine does the Microsoft native Speech Recognition use? Is it the same as being used by the Microsoft Bing Speech API?

Thanks for your answers